# Nintex Workflows in SharePoint 2010

Tags: workflow

I am new to Nintex workflows. Can you please suggest what are the limitations in implementing Nintex workflows? What would be the real things we need to consider when we are implementing them to be placed in cloud 365? Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: Sorry, per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  we do not accept questions about commercial, third-party products.  Instead, please ask your question using the vendor's support site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you cannot host Nintex Workflow on Office 365 without having a Dedicated Office 365 account. My understanding is the Dedicated accounts are for organizations who will have 5,000+ Office 365 users.